# Will the F-stop Loka or Ajna fit a Macbook Pro 15"?

Tags: accessories, f-stop, camera-bag

I'm currently looking at getting a new camera bag that I can use to fit a bit of gear (listed below) and wanted to know if anyone has/had one of these bags and in particular if it will fit a 15" Laptop & what ICU you'd suggest?

I'm looking at either the F-stop Loka or Ajna

I’ve got a Nikon D610 + 16-35mm attached lens,

Macbook pro 15” + chargers and a couple of hardrives

Wacom Tablet/pen & Roostand laptop stand

Manfrotto Pro 4 Tripod ( .5m contracted)

plus Clothes if going overseas or hiking

Thanks!

Comment: This question is better answered by the manufacturer.

Comment: @Blrfl it's academic anyways. F-Stop seems to almost never have their bags in stock. =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have both an F-Stop Ajna and a 15" Macbook Pro 2016.

It will definitely fit but there is no specific place for it. You would have to slide it in behind the ICU if you have a half size ICU or put it in first. I would keep it inside a sleeve or slim case to avoid any scratches.

Note: I don't have an official f-stop ICU I use an old one from a Dakine camera backpack which fills the width and 2/3 of the height on the Ajna. It fits my Canon 6D, 16-35mm L and 70-300mm L and space for another lens or flash.

With that inside there is plenty of room for stuffing in clothes, food and strapping camping gear on the outside for a 1-3 day trip. I have one pair of the gatekeeper straps for attaching my sleeping bag to the top.

Tripods are easily strapped on the outside.

The Ajna is a great pack and has proved to be waterproof so far, mostly used for snow sports photography in BC winter.

I can't comment on the Loka or fitting a Wacom tablet or laptop stand as I don't own any them.